# useEffect only updates useState once

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect

`useEffect` only updates `useState` once on the first render, but if I refresh the page I got an empty list of data.
but when I change something in code.. at first refresh I see the required data of the useState in console, but with every other refresh, I only see an empty array.

```
    const [transaction, setTransaction] = useState([])
    const [family_group, setFamily_group] = useState([])
    const { id } = useParams();

    useEffect(() => {
        getSingleTransaction()

        }
    , [id])

    const getSingleTransaction = async () => {
        const { data } = await axios.get(`/calc/trans/${id}`)
        setTransaction(data)
        setFamily_group(data['family_group'])
    }
    console.log(transaction, "isssssss")
    console.log(family_group, "igggg")
```

now I will see the console log data

but once I refresh the page I will get an empty list of data instead.

Thanks for your advice in advance.

Comment: Try adding `id` to an array (2nd argument in `useEffect`). `, [])` => `, [id])`

Answer (score 1):

`console.log` is not happening before completing `getSingleTransaction` due to async nature.

```
   useEffect(() => {
        getSingleTransaction()
        console.log(transaction)
        console.log(family_group)

        }
    , [])
```

If you add logs inside `getSingleTransaction` and if it logs `id` and `data` then your code is all good.

```
    const getSingleTransaction = async () => {

        console.log(id);

        const { data } = await axios.get(`/calc/trans/${id}`)

        console.log(data);

        setTransaction(data)
        setFamily_group(data['family_group'])
    }
```

Or, Bring the two console logs out of `useEffect` as it will log whenever the state changes.

As @AndreaCostanzo1 has mentioned in the comment add id as a dependency to the `useEffect`.

Comment: @Abdulla Osama, check this out!!

Comment: Furthermore, he's ignoring the warning of the useEffect dependencies missing. Since the function it's outside the scope of useEffect, a warning should pop up. In the current situation, if the ID changes, nothing will change on his interface

Comment: @AmilaSenadheera when i console.log(data) i  see the data, but when i console.log(transaction) still empty array

Comment: @AbdullaOsama, There is no issue then. move the logs outside of the `useEffect`. That will log the updated value always.

Comment: thanks, now it makes sense @AmilaSenadheera

Comment: Maybe also move the function inside the `useEffect` if you are only using it there, or make it accept `id` as a parameter, it will make it a bit more clear that it needs to fire again when the `id` changes

Comment: @AmilaSenadheera sorry for interrupting again , but again im getting an empty array, and when i try to use the data of  `family_group` i get an error that it does not exist

Comment: but when i modify anything in the code , i see the data in the console.log without problem, but when i refresh , it disappears again.

Comment: @Abdulla Osama, you need to check whether data exists, use `Array.isArray(family_group) && family_group.length > 0 && family_group.map(() => ...)`

Comment: I updated my answer again, this is really so annoying..

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
const [transaction, setTransaction] = useState([])
const [family_group, setFamily_group] = useState([])
const { id } = useParams();

useEffect(() => {
  const getSingleTransaction = async (objId) => {
      const { data } = await axios.get(`/calc/trans/${objId}`)
      setTransaction(data)
      setFamily_group(data['family_group'])
  }

  if (id) {
    getSingleTransaction(id)
  }
, [id])

console.log(transaction, "isssssss")
console.log(family_group, "igggg")
```

Comment: this solution works fine, untill I refresh the page, then all the arrays become empty again.